# Can we make a community decision regarding an "interestingness/consequence/relevance/etc." test?

Tags: discussion, notability, scope

I have recently noticed users introducing an "interestingness" or "consequential" test in addition to or in place of our notability requirement.

- [That result doesn't sound very interesting](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/33041/is-exercise-on-a-full-stomach-more-effective-at-burning-calories#comment126010_33041)
- [The claim [...] is irrelevant to anything and overly trivial](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/did-crimean-tatars-collaborate-with-nazi-germanys-crimes-against-humanity#comment125993_32984)
- [The main critique I have of this particular question is: So what? [...] I know the image is charges with horrible imagery, but not sure if this is believed with any consequence.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/is-this-photo-of-a-person-with-ukrainian-flags-swastikas-and-a-super-mario-t-s#comment125861_32924)

In the third example (the only one that has been placed on-hold), our standard notability test would have been sufficient to place the question on-hold.

Can we explicitly accept or reject this triviality/relevance/consequence/interestingness test?

Comment: Ironically, the community seems to find this question uninteresting, even though the question is logical and well-researched.

Answer (score 5):

Uninteresting questions get punished by a lack of upvotes. Questions get upvoted based on how interesting they are, not how well-researched they are. If this wasn't the case, this poorly researched question (the answer was in a link in the very next sentence) wouldn't have got a net score of +57: [Do sea otters rape baby seals to death?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15928/do-sea-otters-rape-baby-seals-to-death)

I don't see an urgent need to deter them with closure as well.

Declaration of interest: I sometimes ask questions the community find uninteresting.